# Two-Ray Ground-Reflection Model: Understanding the Difference in Phase Offsets at the Receiver

Tags: telecommunication, wireless-communication, signal-processing, waves, communication

Currently, I'm trying to understand the Two-Ray Ground-Reflection Model.
During my research, I came across the following simplification expressing the received power as follows (taken from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-ray_ground-reflection_model)):
[image]

The part that is not clear to me is $e^{-j\Delta\phi}$:
How is that derived from $e^{-j2\pi l/\lambda}$ and $e^{-j2\pi (x + x\prime)/\lambda}$?

I know that $\phi$ can be calculated with $\phi = 2\pi d/\lambda$, where $d$ is the distance between the transmitter and the receiver.

In the above equation, the ground-reflected path is expressed as $(x + x\prime)$ and $l$ is the direct line-of-sight path.

Moreover, the approximation only holds if the signal is "narrow band relative to the inverse delay spread $1/\tau$, so that $s ( t ) \approx s ( t − τ )$".

Why is that important?

Thank you for your answers in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The part that is not clear to me is e−jΔϕ: How is that derived from e−j2πl/λ and e−j2π(x+x′)/λ?

Attempting to take $e^{-j2\pi l/\lambda}$ as a common factor we get
$$
\left|e^{-j2\pi l/\lambda}
\right|^2
\left|
\frac{\sqrt{G}}{l}
+\Gamma(\theta)\frac{e^{-j2\pi (x+x\prime)/\lambda}}{(x+x\prime) (e^{-j2\pi l/\lambda})}
\right|^2
$$

On the above, you might have to use the simplifications $\frac{e^a}{e^b} = e^{a-b}$ and $|e^{j\ c}|=1$.

> Moreover, the approximation only holds if the signal is "narrow band relative to the inverse delay spread 1/τ, so that s(t)≈s(t−τ)".
> Why is that important?

They might be interested in finding out the locations or angles for which the signal and its reflected version **destructively interfere** and result in low signal strength. If a signal $s(t)$ and its time delayed version $s(t-\xi)$ needs to cancel out, for all values of $t$, then the assumption above ($s(t)\approx \color{red}{-}^{\dagger}s(t-\xi)$) is required. The word **narrow band** is simply used to indicate that the signal needs to looks like a sinusoidal wave (which has the required property of periodicity mentioned above).

<sup>$\dagger$ The minus sign may be provided by the act of reflection. I am not sure.</sup>